# Junit mock test response blank body

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, junit5

well, i have a problem testing an endpoint which use @ModelAttribute I don't know very well how to test with this annotation and the test response is alwasy an empty body in the MockHttpServletResponse but the status is well...

here is the controller method:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> createTestimonials(@ModelAttribute(name = "testimonialsCreationDto") @Valid TestimonialsCreationDto testimonialsCreationDto) {
    try {
             return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(iTestimonials.createTestimonials(testimonialsCreationDto));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**My dtos**

```
@Getter @Setter @EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestimonialsCreationDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotBlank(message = "{testimonials.error.empty.name}")
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile image;
    private String content;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public interface TestimonialsResponseDto {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getImage();
    String getContent();
    Date getCreated();
    Date getEdited();
    Boolean getDeleted();
}
```

**My test class**

```
@Test
    void createTestimonials() throws Exception {
        //Given
        String name = "Testimonio 159";
        String contentTestimonial = name + " content!";
        Testimonials testimonials = new Testimonials();
        testimonials.setId(123L);
        testimonials.setName(name);
        testimonials.setContent(contentTestimonial);
        TestimonialsCreationDto testimonialsCreationDto = modelMapper.map(testimonials, TestimonialsCreationDto.class);
        TestimonialsResponseDto testimonialsResponseDto = projectionFactory.createProjection(TestimonialsResponseDto.class, testimonialsCreationDto);
        Mockito.when(testimonialsService.createTestimonials(Mockito.any(TestimonialsCreationDto.class))).thenReturn(Mockito.any(TestimonialsResponseDto.class));
        //When
        mockMvc.perform(post("/testimonials")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .flashAttr("testimonialsCreationDto", testimonialsCreationDto)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testimonialsCreationDto))
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8"))
        //Then
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(name)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", is(contentTestimonial)));
        verify(testimonialsService).createTestimonials(isA(TestimonialsCreationDto.class));
    }
```

**Test response**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /testimonials
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"74"]
             Body = {"name":"Testimonio 159","image":null,"content":"Testimonio 159 content!"}
    Session Attrs = {}

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: what are you trying to test here? Basically you are trying to test if your application starts? You either should test  iTestimonials.createTestimonials method or you should check if for specific testimonialsCreationDto object you will return correct json in body

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is this line, where you mock the behaviour of your TestimonialService:

```
Mockito.when(testimonialsService.createTestimonials(Mockito.any(TestimonialsCreationDto.class))).thenReturn(Mockito.any(TestimonialsResponseDto.class));
```

The `thenReturn()` part looks wrong to me. I would expect that your mock should return a concrete `TestimonialsResponseDto` Object.
You could try something like this:

```
when(testimonialsService.createTestimonials(any(TestimonialsCreationDto.class))).then(returnsFirstArg());
```

With this setup your repository will always return the `testimonialsService.createTestimonials(Mockito.any(TestimonialsCreationDto.class))` that was passed into it.

**EDIT**
Maybe you want to return the `testimonialsResponseDto` that is not used in your code anywhere?

```
when(testimonialsService.createTestimonials(any(TestimonialsCreationDto.class))).then(testimonialsResponseDto);
```

If you need an example on how to work with @WebMvcTest, maybe you find [this blog post of mine](https://jschmitz.dev/2021/04/14/how_to_test_the_web_layer_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_webmvctest/) helpful :)

Comment: i tried that but respond me the same error, empty body D:
"java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name""